# How to get the current value of animation slider on Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, animation, slider, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to Plotly and Dash. May I know how to get the current value of the animation slider?

What I did here is clicking the button to find out the current value of animation slider. I tried to use 'fig.layout.sliders[0].active' but it always returns the same index, which is 0, even though the slider is at other value.
For example, I would like to get the current value of the animation in the picture below, which is 1972 (index at 4). I thought 'fig.layout.sliders[0].active' would return 4 but it always returns 0(the starting index, 1952) .

EDIT: Let me give a clearer scenario here.
I clicked the Play button and the animation slider started to move from 1952 to 2007(as shown in the picture). I stopped the animation slide at '1972' with the label of 'year=1972'.
Then, when I pressed the 'Click Me' Button, it should print '4' because 1972 is at index 4 of the animation_frame. However, it printed '0'. No matter at which year I stopped the animation slider, it would just print '0'
[image: snapshot]

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.bar(df, x="continent", y="pop", color="continent", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country", range_y=[0,4000000000])

layout = html.Div([
    html.Label(id='test', children=[]),
    html.Button('Click me', id='btn'),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-map', figure=fig ),

])


@app.callback(Output('test', 'children'),
              [Input(component_id='btn', component_property='n_clicks')])
def testing(value):
    if value:
        print('can',fig.layout.sliders[0].active)
    return ['dummy']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure without the complete setup of your app. But from yout figure setup, you can retrieve the label of a frame using:

```
fig.layout.sliders[0].steps[0].label
```

Which returns `'1952'`

And

```
fig.layout.sliders[0].steps[-1].label
```

Will return `'2007'`

I hope this helps. If not, then please consier sharing all details about your app and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but it does not answer my doubt. Let me give a scenario here. 
I clicked the Play button and the animation slider started to move from 1952 to 2007(as shown in the picture). I stopped the animation slide at '1972' with the label of 'year=1972'.
Then, when I pressed the 'Click Me' Button, it should print '4' because 1972 is at index 4 of the animation_frame. However, it printed '0'. No matter at which year I stopped the animation slider, it would just print '0'

Comment: @LYHooi The provided code will not reproduce your figure. If you share a completely runnable app I'll take another look.